# Concurrent Access Safety at Spring Beans

Tags: java, spring

I have current method:

```
private int getStatusCode(String path) throws IOException {
  HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
  HttpGet method = new HttpGet(path);
  HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(method);
  return httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();        
}
```

I want to put it in a Spring `@Service` class. Then I want to use that class as `@Autowired`. I know that Spring beans are singleton so there will be only one instance of my autowired class. I have different `@Controller` classes which use that service. Does concurrent accesses makes a problem at my case? For example overriding path from another request?

Answer (score 0):

> Does concurrent accesses makes a problem at my case?

Although it is a singleton, tt doesn't cause any concurrency issues because the method`getStatusCode` uses only the

- objects that are passed to the method as parameters(ex: String path)
- Objects that are created with in the method.

> For example overriding path from another request?

Not an issue because each method call will be from different threads and parameters to method (like path variable) are stored on the stack which is distinct for each thread.

As an real time example we have take look at the Servlet. Only one instance of the servlet is created by the servlet container irrespective of number of requests. All the request threads access this single servlet instance's `(doGet(...) or doPost(...))` methods by passing their own `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects to the above methods and it doesn't result mixing-up the requests/responses ever.